# CloudFront issue: 99% of the devices under CloudFront Viewers show up as unknown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, amazon-cloudfront

I am very new to CloudFront. I was able to get it up and running and now I want to check the user stats. However, devices, browsers, and OS all show that 99.68% of the requests are from unknown. Any way to get around this?

Comment: What is in the front of CloudFront ? Do you have a proxy to access the cloudfront url?

Comment: Depends on what devices you are targeting. Cloudfront isn't great at figuring out device. I manage a Cloudfront that is used for streaming, and we see a large amount of unknown devices as well. For us, it looks like it might be Playstation and Smart TV devices that end up unidentified mostly.

Comment: The front of the cloudfront is a static website which is on an S3 bucket. The good thing is we get accurate locations. The unknown devices isn't a huge issue. I just wanted to see if it was common. Thanks!